# grep multiple pattern from read input

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

so i made a bash script the greps the name of the host on the redirected file. However, there are hosts that are named either with "-" or "_"

GTR_SRV123_EST
GTR-SRV123-EST

Right now, what i did was, grep just a portion of the FQDN, like **SRV123**

Is there a way i can grep the host even if i just put the FQDN **GTR_SRV123_EST** and it will still matched this **GTR-SRV123-EST**.

i have a prompt that ask for the hostname:

```
echo -n "Please enter the host: "
read $host


grep -i $host ${temp}/*
```

update:
so had it working with the help of Juan's command. However, the directory path is displayed on the output. How can i get rid of it.

```
/export/home/aa12s/GLB-TXU/temp/
```

Current output:

```
/export/home/aa12s/GLB-TXU/temp/GBL-ASA-A:100022FBC0D00038 gbl-asa-a-mode1 5005076801103673 active gbl-ac-wbg02
```

Desired output:

```
GBL-ASA-A:100022FBC0D00038 gbl-asa-a-mode1 5005076801103673 active gbl-ac-wbg02
```

Command:

```
grep -iE "$(echo $host| awk -F '/export/home/aa12s/GLB-TXU/temp/' '{$2=$1;a=gsub(/_/, "-",$2); print $1"|"$2}' 2>/dev/null)" ${temp}/*
```

Comment: `grep -iE "$(echo $host| awk '{$2=$1;a=gsub(/_/, "-",$2); print $1"|"$2}' 2>/dev/null)" config/temp/*|awk -F \/ '{print $NF}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Kind of hacky* but give this a try:

```
grep -Ei "$(echo $host| awk '{$2=$1;gsub(/_/, "-",$2);print $1"|"$2}' 2>/dev/null)" ${temp}/*
```

To get rid of filepaths:

```
grep -iE "$(echo $host| awk '{$2=$1;gsub(/_/, "-",$2);print $1"|"$2}' 2>/dev/null)" ${temp}/* 2>/dev/null|awk -F \/ '{print $NF}'
```

**NOTE**: Slashes must NOT be present in the file content.

Comment: so i tried using `-ei` but it prints all the information from the file.. Instead, i used `-iE` and it works. However, this directory path (/export/home/aa12s/GLB-TXU/temp/) is included from the output. Tried removing it by adding `-F /export/home/aa12s/GLB-TXU/temp/` and it didn't work.. any work around to remove it?

Comment: Bingo!! Thanks, brother @Juan Diego Godoy. You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your pattern.

```
echo -n "Please enter the host: "
read host # Edit: not $host
host="${host//[_-]/\[_-\]}" # turn either into a *check* for either

grep -i "$host" ${temp}/*
```

Comment: This breaks is they give you `GTR[-_]SRV123[-_]EST` as the pattern, lol

Comment: unfortunately, hostnames are different from one another... it can be `glb_servername_bas1, servername_bas1, glb_servername`.. so it's quite hard to filter the pattern :(

Comment: all I did was a global replace on `-` and `_` so that they always search for *either*. Doesn't that resolve the question as asked? if the user types `GLB-SERVERNAME`, then `grep -i "glb[-_]servername" ${temp}/*` still finds it, no?

Comment: No there's no output.

Comment: Please edit the OP with an example file as in `${temp}/*` and specific examples of what you want to allow entered as `host` with the desired resulting output.

Comment: Hi @Paul, so basically, the grep function is working now as desired using the command by Juan. `grep -iE "$(echo $host| awk '{$2=$1;a=gsub(/_/, "-",$2); print $1"|"$2}' 2>/dev/null)" ${temp}/*`. However,  the output includes the directory path which is `/export/home/aa12s/GLB-TXU/temp/`.  <br/>  which now looks like this <br/> Question now is, how can i removed this part `/export/home/aa12s/GLB-TXU/temp/` <br/> And leave only `GBL-ASA-A:100022FBC0D00038 gbl-asa-a-mode1 5005076801103673 active gbl-ac-wbg02`

Comment: Assign the grep return to a `var`, then `var="${var##*/}"`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no host name with both _ and - below will work.

## Entered host contains only _

```
grep -iE $(echo $host | tr "_" "-")\|$host ${temp}/*
```

## Entered host contains only -

```
grep -iE $(echo $host | tr "-" "_")\|$host ${temp}/*
```

## Entered host contains both _ and -

```
grep -iE $(echo $host | tr "_" "-")\|$(echo $host | tr "-" "_")\|$host ${temp}/*
```

Comment: tried the 3 and none works. :( I guess it's entered host that contains either _ or -

Comment: Can you please share the host entered and expected results once again?

Comment: this code basically help me out. `grep -ei "$(echo $host| awk '{$2=$1;a=gsub(/_/, "-",$2);print $1"|"$2}' 2>/dev/null)" ${temp}/*` .However, this path `/export/home/aa12s/GLB-TXU/temp/'` also displays from the output. Do you know how i can get rid of it? I tried adding `-F '/export/home/aa12s/GLB-TXU/temp/'` but it's still there.

Comment: would you be able to help me out to remove this path `/export/home/aa12s/GLB-TXU/temp/` please :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use backreference :

```
([_-]) : capture either _ ou - in group 1
\1 : reference group 1
```

try this command :

```
grep -iE "([_-])$host\1" ${temp}/*
```

https://regex101.com/r/uH5SHC/1/

Wiyh `host=SRV123`, you will capture :

- GTR_SRV123_EST
- GTR-SRV123-EST

and not

- GTR_SRV123-EST

Comment: tried this is got the error `grep: Invalid back reference`